# Is it possible to add,delete xml nodes with jquery $.ajax?

Tags: jquery, xml, addition

I want to delete some nodes or add some nodes in xml with jquery,
I try it with `append`, `empty`, `remove` but all of them seem to not work,
like (**in $.ajax**):

```
success:function(xml){
    $(xml).find("layout").append('<app id="' + $children.eq(i).attr("id") + '"></app>');
    $(xml).find("layout").empty();
}
```

also I find there is no tutorial on google.
So I wonder is it possible add or delete nodes in xml with jquery?

**OK ,I write it in details**,the xml file just save in local domain as Database/UserConfig/config.xml
here is my **Ajax code**:

```
function layout_change()
{
    var $children=$input.children();

    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "Database/UserConfig/config.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        timeout: 2000,
        beforesend:function(xml){
            $(xml).find("layout").empty();
        },
        success:function(xml){
            for(var i=0;i<$children.length;i++)
            {
                $(xml).find("layout").append('<app id="' + $children.eq(i).attr("id") + '"></app>');              
            }
        },
        error:function(){}
    });
}
```

or it can be done with javascript?or can be only done with server language like C#?……

here is my demo xml：

```
<layout>
        <app id="id-4"></app>
        <app id="id-5"></app>
        <app id="id-6"></app>
        <app id="id-1"></app>
        <app id="id-2"></app>
        <app id="id-3"></app>   
</layout>
```

Comment: if you can do something with javascript ,there are high chances that it can be done...with jquery

Comment: But you shouldn't write or update xml files , text files from javascript , that is not good approach , javascript is mainly to manipulate DOM , fetch data and show...,send data.

Comment: @alex , do you think it is a good approach to update xml , if he wants he should use data property and use jquery meta data plugin

Comment: @gov That's not true. jQuery is an *excellent* tool for parsing XML.

Comment: @alex , parsing is fine , i am asking about updating xml??

Comment: @hh54188 we need more code to help you. In particular, your complete `$.ajax()` call, and your server-side code that gives you the xml. *Is* it your datasource? Is it a cross-domain request? etc. Bottom line, we need more info and code.

Comment: @hh54 , can you tell me the reason why you want to change xml from jquery.???

Comment: @hh54 if you write back something to xml , you need to make a ajax call to backend like c# ,or java and that server side code should update the xml. and then you should make a call back again to see the latest results. You shouldn't directly manipulate the xml file from jquery.

Comment: @gov I want save the xml as user personal config,because the elements on page can be drag or moved ,the lay out can be changed often,so I want immediately save it when the layout changed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

jQuery is a fantastic tool for parsing and manipulating XML in javascript. jQuery's ajax APIs were, in fact, built with this in mind which is why you're able to specify the response type of an ajax call by setting the `dataType` argument to `xml` (although they do try to do some auto-detection if this argument is omitted). From the jQuery `$.ajax()` documentation for the `dataType` argument:

> "xml": Returns a XML document that can
>   be processed via jQuery.

You can parse and manipulate XML as much as want using jQuery. I'll have to add that using CSS selectors is wonderful compared to XPath queries in server-side XML libraries.

While `empty` and `remove` work as expected, there's a gotcha when adding nodes on the fly with functions like `append`: jQuery, for whatever reason (I haven't really dug into this), won't create the element for you when appending to the XML structure (although this works fine in HTML structures). You can get around this easily by explicitly creating the node yourself as a DOM element or jQuery object and then calling `append`:

```
//Either of these will work
var elem = document.createElement('app');
xml.find('layout').append(elem); // Appends <app></app> to <layout>
xml.find('layout').append($('<app>')); // Does the same

// You can also you use other manipulation functions such as `attr`
xml.find('layout').append($('<app>').attr('id', 'ego'));
```

It looks like, however, that there are other problems with your code that would be preventing it from behaving as expected. The `$.ajax` `beforeSend` callback, for example, passes in the `XMLHttpRequest` object to the callback function and not your XML object to be manipulated. The result is that your `empty` call in that callback does nothing.

Also, if you're trying to manipulate the response of `Database/UserConfig/config.xml` in the `beforeSend` callback, it probably won't have existed yet since `beforeSend` is called before the ajax request is fired off. It's possible that the `xml` argument you intended to pass in was scoped globally, but it's squashed in the scope of the callback since jQuery is passing in `XMLHttpRequest` as I mentioned before.